# Create group variable over time with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset of daily observations for about 200 American firms over a twenty-year period. I want to construct a group-variable taking values 1-10 every day, depending on for example the size of the firm. I am using data.table and the function ntile(size,10) to create the groups.

I tried

```
DT[,decile:=(ntile(size,10)),by=date]
```

but it did not work.
`DT` is my data.table, which includes the variables date, size, price, companyid, etc

Comment: What didn't work exactly? Is the result not as expected? Was there an error?

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: A reproducible example with some simulated data would be helpful

Comment: The assignment (`:=`) would not work as the original dataset have different number of rows than the new `ntile` output.  Please show a small reproducible example and your expected output based on that

Comment: My intention is to create 10 groups, each consisting of about 20 companies. Group 1 will be the 20 smallest firms at day t ,measured by the Size variable, Group 2 the 20 second smallest firms day t, etc, and then Group 10 is the 20 largest firms at day t.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple toy example:`DT = data.table( name=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"), 
                 date=1:4, 
                 size=c(100, 101, 103, 102, 50, 51, 50 ,49, 200, 201, 202, 205, 95, 96, 98, 110) )
DT[,decile:=(ntile(size,2)),by=date]`

Answer (score 0):

Using a slightly larger example data set, I can construct a group variable as follows:

```
# sample data
DT = data.table(
  firm= rep(LETTERS, each = 20),
  date = 1:20,
  size = sample(1:250, length(LETTERS) * 20, replace = TRUE))

# sort and assign group rank
setkey(DT, date, size)
DT[, grouprank := (1:.N) %/% 10L, by = date]
```

That will assign a size group rank to each firm on each separate date, as can be seen from a subset of the result for a single date:

```
DT[date == 1]

    firm date size grouprank
 1:    J    1   15         0
 2:    L    1   37         0
 3:    K    1   57         0
 4:    Q    1   64         0
 5:    R    1   64         0
 6:    C    1   81         0
 7:    E    1   86         0
 8:    I    1  106         0
 9:    O    1  117         0
10:    B    1  118         1
11:    X    1  119         1
12:    A    1  135         1
13:    H    1  138         1
14:    D    1  140         1
15:    F    1  162         1
16:    N    1  171         1
17:    M    1  178         1
18:    S    1  178         1
19:    T    1  181         1
20:    G    1  188         2
21:    Y    1  196         2
22:    P    1  204         2
23:    W    1  205         2
24:    V    1  244         2
25:    Z    1  245         2
26:    U    1  247         2
    firm date size grouprank
```